# How to run a docker image based on its previous image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using docker to run an application but every time i need to update the application on production, i have to build on a new image locally, push/pull and run it on production, but the application is almost 5gb.
Is there a way to just push the changes, push them and then run the new image with the changes based on its previous image?

any help on this matter?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/

Answer (score 0):

1. Docker's layer caching mechanism to reduce the amount of data that needs to be transferred when updating your application.
2. If you have static data that remains constant - You can mount a directory using -v tag to get the contents of folder in your image

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the other answers mention (in very specific language, btw) using the layer caching mechanism, they haven't said *how*.

The important thing is to have the code that changes at the *end* of your Dockerfile. That way, later builds can use the cached layers that don't change, and only rebuild (and push/pull) the layers with new stuff in.